# navigating to a product from an api

Tags: reactjs

> hey there, I'm working on an e-commerce project, i have a fake store api with products, i called the api and listed all the products and now i'm trying to navigate to each product without creating a component for each product, can someone give me an idea how to do that? thanks in advance.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'


const Womenclothes = () => {

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);


    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPosts = async () => {
          setLoading(true);
          const res = await axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/women\'s%20clothing');
          setPosts(res.data);
          setLoading(false)
        }
    
        fetchPosts();
        }, [])
    
        if(loading) {
        return <h2>loadijng...</h2>

    }


    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
        <ul className='itemsList'>
           {posts.map(post => (
               <li className='items' key={post.id}>
                   <h1 className='title'>{post.title}</h1>
                   <span className='itemOrg'>
                       <img onClick={productId} className='prodiMG' src={post.image} alt="pic"/>
                       <h3 className='des'>{post.description}</h3>
                       <h2>${post.price}</h2>
                       
                   </span>
                   
               </li>
           ))} 
        </ul>

        </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Womenclothes
```

Comment: Hi I just want to clarify you question so correct me if I am wrong, when you say "i'm trying to navigate to each product without creating a component for each product" do you want to be able to click on a product and have it direct to another page with the details of that product?

Comment: yes exactly @Danoram

Comment: @Danoram you don't have to write me the whole code just put me in the right direction of how to do it myself

Comment: Sure thing. Let me just put together something quick that won't exactly answer your question but will hopefully put you in the right direction

Comment: This may or may not be of use to use. I want be offended if it isn't. [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-surf-b81xf?file=/src/App.js) It's an example that you can modify to fit what you need. I think the most important thing that you want is just the navigating between components using `react-router-dom`.

Comment: thanks, that's certainly helpful, there're few stuff that I still don't understand because I'm still learning but I can manage with google, thanks again. @Danoram

Comment: @Danoram just wanted to let you know that it worked, thanks for the help.

Comment: Sweet! Awesome work!